# Javac doesn't compile java class dependent on both jars and classes

Tags: java, compiler-errors, javac

I have a Java class which is dependent on quite a lot of jar files and a couple of classes in the same directory where I execute `javac` command

When I tried to compile it like this:

```
javac -cp ".:dependencies/*" Loader.java
```

It does include all of the jars in the `dependencies` folder, however, it doesn't work with `.java` files in the same folder where `Loader.java` is located.

How can I resolve it?

I've tried to move all the dependent `.java` files to `dependencies` but it didn't work.

It still tells me that there are errors related to not finding symbol

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also tried to go one directory up and compile it from there, still no success

Comment: Please try `javac -cp ".:dependencies/*:"`. Like miss `:`

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't work :(

Comment: What error did you getting?